# Is it possible to store Jalali date in created_at and updated_at field using timestamp in laravel?

Tags: laravel, date, timestamp, field, store

Is it possible to store Jalali date in created_at and updated_at field using timestamp in laravel?

I have searched and tried but I could not
if it is possible how should I do it?

somebody help me please

Comment: choose `datetime` format, instead of `timestamp` in your SQL

Comment: No, I don't think you can directly store it in the database as a date. You need to convert it from/to gregorian date in your models, or store it as a string and convert it from string to date (and back) in your models. Either way take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: From a google search take a look at https://github.com/p3ym4n/jdate it might be helpful when creating casts though it seems unmaintained so use at your own risk

Comment: its type is already in datetime